# Prevent rake migrate from creating foreign key constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

We have a case in which one of the table column name use a suffix "_id".  The migration code :

```
create_table :companies do |t|
  t.integer :ref_id  
  t.string :name
end
```

When running db:migrate, it fails, because rails tried to create a foreign key constraint for ref_id, and found that there is no table called "refs".  In our case "ref_id" is not a foreign key.

Is there a way for us to prevent rails to create foreign key constraint for that column?

Comment: AFAIK that shouldn't be your case. It never happens. Show your full migration.

Comment: It happened that its because we have schema plus gem which makes rails to create foreign key constraint automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have a `schema_plus` gem. You can do:

```
create_table :companies do |t|
  t.integer :ref_id, foreign_key: false  
  t.string :name
end
```